# CSS does not work with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, css

So I have a problem here. I have set some custom styles for a few divs to make them temporarily invisible. However these custom styles does not seem to trigger when I generate text from an outside .js file with the document write function:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .section 
        {
            display: none;
        }
        .section#form1
        {
            display: block;
        }
```

JavaScript function to toggle visibility:

```
function toggleVisibility(newSection) 
        {
            $(".section").not("#" + newSection).hide();
            $("#" + newSection).show();
        }
```

Somewhere inside my recursive loop function that generates most of the content on this page I have this

```
...
if (step != 1)
                    {
                        document.write("</div>");
                    }
                    document.write("<div id='form"+step+"' class='section'>");
...
```

Do I need some sort of code to assign where JavaScript prints out all the elements of my form to a certain outer div? I can't seem to understand why all the divs are visible at the beginning, I did the same code earlier and it worked just fine then. Perhaps a good alternative to document.write might do the trick. Feels like document.write sorta overrides everything.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {       
        $('#show-results').click(function() 
        {
            $.post('JSAAN.php', function(data) 
            {
                var pushedData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                // Uses the function from loop.js
                document.write("<form id='evalForm' onsubmit='return false;'>");
                var fieldsetActive = 0;
                loop(pushedData);
            })
        })
    });
```

And the loop function (who's in a separate file starts like this:

```
function loop(obj) {
    // Starts the form
        $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
            if($.isPlainObject(val) || $.isArray(val)) { // object, call recursively
```

Comment: You should just use a DOM inspector tool to look at the style rules being applied once your finished page loads in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `document.write` to create your `div`, consider using `document.createElement`.

```
var elem = document.createElement('div'),
    formStep = 'form' + step;
elem.setAttribute('id', formStep);
elem.setAttribute('class', 'section');
```

This will insert the element into the DOM. `document.write` is not recommended for this type of usage.

If you need to use jQuery:

```
// using document.createElements('div') as the selector is the fastest way
var elem = $(document.createElement('div')),
    formStep = 'form' + step;
elem.attr('id', formStep).attr('class', 'section');
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Couldn't you also do `$('<div/>')`?

Comment: This works for input/label/fieldset etc too, couldnt get it to work immediately. Works wonders for the div though.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `document.write`.  If the page is fully loaded, it will erase the entire page (including the CSS).

You seem to be using jQuery already, so use its `.append` or `.html` methods instead.

Comment: Seems like a perfect answer, just can't get it to work. I load my loop.js file in the header, and inside I am trying to create divs and all the other stuff like this. The main.html file has a div with id="poll". Should be correct no?

$("#poll").append("<div name='form"+step+"' class='section'>");

Comment: @Tom: That looks right..... Is your code in a `$(function(){})` block (`$(document).ready(function(){})`)?  You may be looking for `$('#poll')` before it exists.

Comment: Added some snippets at the question, I think they should be right. A bit unsure about how included file loop.js behaves under these circumstances.

Comment: I mean would it still count as if it is inside document.ready if it's being loaded as <script src="loop.js"> and called inside document.ready ?

Comment: @Tom: If it's just a function, it doesn't need to be in document.ready.  Only the call to it does (if it accesses DOM elements).  Also, make sure the function is in scope when it's being called.

Answer (score 0):

because when you use `document.write` it overwrites everything in the page including styles etc, I think you should consider using DOM functions instead of using `document.write`